# If a trigger on an Oracle DB table fails to execute successfully or does not compile, can it impact the base table?

Tags: oracle

let's say there are tables a and b.
There is an AFTER INSERT trigger on a, that copies the row data to b.

If, during the execution of the trigger, there is an error does it impact table a in any way?
If the trigger does not compile, because it's ill-defined, does it impact table a?

I want to add a trigger to a table that is 'not mine'. I want to evaluate the risk that this can potentially pose.

Cheers

============== edit ================

I verified that - by handling the error (as suggested in the reply) - it now does not impact the base table.

```js
create table tableA (column1 number);
create table tableB (column1 number, CONSTRAINT constraintName PRIMARY KEY (column1));

create or replace TRIGGER tableA_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
--

BEGIN
insert into tableB values (1);

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occured but ignored.');

END;

insert into tableA values (1);
insert into tableA values (1);
```

After that, tableA had two records, tableB only 1.

Without the exception handling, both tables would only have one record each, and after the first insert it would have shown an exception in the SQL Developer window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will impact the base table.

If there is error in insert trigger it will not allow to insert any record in base table. Same applies to all type of triggers.

Also, Adding DML triggers to tables affects the performance of DML statements on those tables.

According to [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm):

> If a predefined or user-defined error condition or exception is raised
> during the execution of a trigger body, then all effects of the
> trigger body, as well as the triggering statement, are rolled back
> (unless the error is trapped by an exception handler). Therefore, a
> trigger body can prevent the execution of the triggering statement by
> raising an exception. User-defined exceptions are commonly used in
> triggers that enforce complex security authorizations or integrity
> constraints.

Comment: Thanks! So its bad if the exception is not handled. I edited my post above and added an EXCEPTION block with no content. So basically there is an exception handler now, but which does nothing. Will this still prevent the insertion of the record?

Comment: @baouss: there's a simple way to determine this - write some test code and find out.

Comment: Tried it and when handling it with WHEN OTHERS the inserted records that was the trigger is visible in the table. So handling any exception seems to be the workaround, which I guess should be done anyways :D

Comment: I have edited my question to describe the solution. Thanks to all of you.